# Is there a pre-existing haarcascade .xml file for frown detection which can be used to detect whether a person is frowning or sad?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, feature-detection

I wish to use it with Opencv in python. I know that i could create a custom cascade classifier, but i don't have time to do that. Is there a better or faster way to do this?? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to do something similar to this -
 http://elarosca.net/video.ogv

In order to accomplish your task download the following github respository https://github.com/mihaelacr/pydeeplearn/tree/master/code/webcam-emotion-recognition and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps